# Ubuntu not installing

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb, 22.04, usb-installation

I have an old laptop with a Blue Screen of Death issue, unable to login to Windows at all. I tried to reset and everything and even in the middle of the reset gives the BSOD.

So I decided to swap to Linux, I downloaded Ubuntu 22.04.3 and used Rufus to create the bootable USB.
I tried to boot it from the BIOS. It showed me the options to "Try or install Ubuntu"
I selected that option, the laptop started booting and then just showed me the Ubuntu desktop.
However, keyboard and mousepad not responding. I was not able to install Linux or nothing.

I have to force shut down to get back to the BIOS.
Am I doing something wrong?

[image]

Comment: most likely something is wrong with the hardware, the physical laptop itself. Especially if Windows BSOD-ed while reinstalling.

Comment: Anything I can do determine what's the root cause? Can it be the drive, RAM, or something else I can replace perhaps?

Comment: It could be that drive setting in UEFI needs to be AHCI. Or it could be Windows fast startup or bitlocker has locked all partitions, so installer will not see drive. What brand/model system? Post this from terminal in live installer: `sudo parted -l` If that shows partitions then not hardware. If not shown, then maybe a new SSD is in your future.

Comment: Please tell us more about the computer: brand name and model? Tell us also about the graphics card/chip: brand name and model?

Comment: Laptop Asus Q524U , BIOS version 307 , Processor Intel Core i7-7500U , RAM 12GB , Intel HD Graphics 620 and NVIDIA GeForce 940MX , 2000 GB storage. It consider it's a good laptop and I'd like to bring it back to life.

Comment: The SATA mode  is AHCI. That's the only option. I can't access to terminal to enter the command sudo parted -l

Comment: I suspect problems with the nvidia graphics. Please try with the [boot option](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389&p=13370808#post13370808) `nomodeset`. If it helps you get working graphics, the next step is to install a proprietary nvidia driver to release the full power of the graphics card.

Comment: Still no keyboard/mouse? Try to plug some usb devices